# Android Create vibration pattern like Samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, vibration, android-vibration

I'm trying to create a View with touch events to create a vibration pattern like samsung does.

[image]

I use CountDownTimer to start recording during 5 seconds. I want to catch ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events from touch.

Are there a library to create this circle view with the timer animation? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Note Samsung may have licensed a library like Immersion Haptic to build out the intricate effects: http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=110&Itemid=503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can keep track of the timer in something like milliseconds, you can log the action down and action up with the time.

Example:
Action down @ Second 1
Action up @ Second 1.5

When you try to recreate this, you can rebuild the same way you recorded. Start a timer, and when Second = 1, vibrate. When second = 1.5, stop vibrating

Answer (score 1):

There few really amazing libraries for circle views - you can find them on [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40), under Graphics category. I think most useful for you is [DecoView](https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting). This library is designed for circle animations.

Also few flexible libraries which support circle charts are [EazeGraph](https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph) and [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Last one is really powerful.